# How to Avoid "Wstringop-overflow" Warning When One Has to Rely on Source Length?

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, gcc-warning

I'm getting the `Wstringop-overflow` warning when using `strncat` to pass command-line arguments to my program. I understand that the compiler is complaining because I'm using source length to append the destination, but how else can I implement this to prevent the warning? Here is my code:

```
static char ttyPort[MAX_NAME_SIZE];
bzero(ttyPort,MAX_NAME_SIZE);

strncat(ttyPort, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]) + 1);
```

Here is the Warning:

```
../tun/main.c:24:5: warning: ‘strncat’ specified bound depends on the length of the source argument [-Wstringop-overflow=]
     strncat(ttyPort, argv[2], argsLen + 1);
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../tun/main.c:23:15: note: length computed here
     argsLen = strlen(argv[2]);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I already tried the following but the compiler still picks up on it:

```
uint8_t argsLen;
argsLen = strlen(argv[2]);

strncat(ttyPort, argv[2], argsLen + 1);
```

Comment: You should not use `strlen(argv[2]) + 1` as the size argument, as that could lead to overflow of `ttyPort`. Instead use the size of `ttyPort` itself. And why use `bzero` (which is obsolete) and `strncat` instead of plain `strncpy`?

Comment: Think about it: `strncat(ttyPort, argv[2], strlen(argv[2]) + 1);` is equivalent to `strcat(ttyPort, argv[2]);` (and equally as dangerous).

Comment: To ensure you do not overrun `ttyPort[]` and ensure it is null-terminated, you can do: `strncpy(ttyPort, argv[2], MAX_NAME_SIZE - 1); ttyPort[MAX_NAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0';`.

Comment: Thank you all, I like your suggestions. One other question, why is it not safe to assume that `argv[2]` is null-terminated? After all, it is passed on from the Shell.

Comment: I just confirmed that all command-line arguments are null-terminated by taking a memory dump during debug mode, so that answers my last question. I guess then Ian's suggestion would be the answer. That is, use `strncpy(ttyPort, argv[2], MAX_NAME_SIZE - 1);`. `ttyPort[MAX_NAME_SIZE - 1] = '\0';` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the remaining size of the destination array like below, without using any source related lengths. -1 is for the null termination char.

```
strncat(ttyPort, argv[2], sizeof(ttyPort) - strlen(ttyPort) - 1);
```